# How to extract data from first brackets from SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server

How to extract data only between first bracket from a SQL Server column?

Column data looks like this:

```
       Pace - (SPE)-Elkart IN (OEM Sales)
       Pace - (CIS) - San Francisco (CIS)
       Pietila, Robert (4060)
       Pace - (STP) - St Paul Manufacturing
```

Desired results:

```
       SPE
       CIS
       4060
       STP
```

Comment: String manipulation in T-SQL is exceptionally poor and clunky. Point in case: `SUBSTRING(column, PATINDEX('%(%)%', column), CHARINDEX(')', column, PATINDEX('%(%)%', column)) - PATINDEX('%(%)%', column) + 1)`. And note that this *still* fails on nested parentheses.

Comment: The above code gives and output : (SPE), (CIS), (4060), (STP) I am looking just for the chracheters withtin the brackets : SPE, CIS, 4060, STP

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Then you want the string to start one position later, and end two positions sooner than it does now. Modifying the expression to achieve this should not be hard -- if it is, that's all the more reason to not do this in T-SQL at all, but some ETL pipeline/tool where transforming strings and matching patterns is much more convenient.

Comment: As mentionned, string manipulation in sql server is not the best. Is it absolutely required to be done via the sql query or could the receiving client manipulate the string (ie: report manager, client code, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Pace - (SPE)-Elkart IN (OEM Sales)'),
('Pace - (CIS) - San Francisco (CIS)'),
('Pietila, Robert (4060)'),
('Pace - (STP) - St Paul Manufacturing'),
('fafa'),
('dada )NO(');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
    , result = IIF(start > 0 and [end] > 0 AND [end] > start, SUBSTRING(tokens, start + 1, [end] - start -1), NULL)
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT start = CHARINDEX('(', tokens), [end] = CHARINDEX(')', tokens)) AS t;
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | start | end | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pace - (SPE)-Elkart IN (OEM Sales) | 8 | 12 | SPE |
| 2 | Pace - (CIS) - San Francisco (CIS) | 8 | 12 | CIS |
| 3 | Pietila, Robert (4060) | 17 | 22 | 4060 |
| 4 | Pace - (STP) - St Paul Manufacturing | 8 | 12 | STP |
| 5 | fafa | 0 | 0 | NULL |
| 6 | dada )NO( | 9 | 6 | NULL |